# How to safely share an array between main thread and background thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an array (myData) in MyApplication class which I use to populate a list view in MainActivity using a BaseAdapter.

Now I need to do some processing with the array which would require updating the array items. How do I allow the background thread to thread-safely update the array and at the same time, display the content of the array in my main thread?

Partial **MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private List<MyData> myData;
    private MyApplication instance;

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public List<MyData> getMyData(){
        return myData;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        myData = new ArrayList<>();
    }    
}
```

Partial **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ListView myList;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_list);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        myAdapter.setData(MyApplication.getInstance().getMyData());
        myList.setAdapter(myAdapter); 
        //myList also listens to onItemClick
    }
}
```

Partial **MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private List<MyData> data;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setData(List<MyData> data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Partial **MyIntentService.java**

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService{
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        List<MyData> data = MyApplication.getInstance().getMyData();
        //beside re-arranging, there might also be an update and delete item
        if(updated){
            //notify broadcast receiver in MainActivity that array has been updated
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(ARRAY_UPDATED));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `BroadcastReceiver` to update data at method `onHandleIntent`

Comment: _Updated question with LocalBroadcastManager_. I'm already notifying `MainActivity` via a `LocalBroadcastManager`. However, I'm not convinced that this is the correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two quite different cases, depending on what you mean by "update".

**Change content of the list while it is being in use:**

If by "update" you mean that you would like to add/remove elements to/from list in BG thread, while the same list is being concurrently read on UI thread, then a thread safe implementation of `List` interface would be sufficient. Check the documentation of [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

**Change particular items in the array while it is being in use:**

If by "update" you meant that you would like to alter specific list's element (e.g. `myData.get(0).setPropery("some property")`), then the situation is more complex. In order to perform such an action safely, implementations of each particular object type contained withing the list must be thread-safe. The safest would be to combine a thread-safe implementation of `List` with a thread-safe implementation(s) of `MyData`.